# Moving to Germany with partner and small child

Tags: united-kingdom, germany

I am currently a UK resident and both me and my partner are EU nationals. We have jobs here, but she will soon go on maternity leave. Her limited duration contract will end while she's on maternity leave and it might or might not be renewed (we don't know yet due to unexpected circumstances). She will receive some maternity allowance and also statutory maternity pay (SMP).

We've been thinking about moving to Germany for a while, but are not sure about the timing. On the one hand, the fact that she'll potentially have to look for another job seems to be a good opportunity to move as she wouldn't lose much by leaving the UK now, but having a little child complicates our situation.

The UK Government website says that benefits such as maternity allowance and SMP are transferable to Germany (for UK citizens, but I assume this would apply to us as well), but I am a bit worried about the period after that. First, would the fact that only one of us works while the other is taking care of our child be a problem for our residency permit? Also, it seems that moms of little children who return to work relatively soon after giving birth are frowned upon and places in nurseries and kindergartens are difficult to get, which brings me to my second concern: in your experience, would she be able to return  work after say 12 months of maternity leave? She'd much rather have a job and not rely on benefits, but if that's absolutely not possible, would we be entitled to any kind of financial support from the government?

We won't definitely move until summer at least, but I would like to hear about your opinion/experience whether this is a very bad moment to go to Germany and we should rather wait for our child to be a bit older.

We'd prefer to move to (or close to) a city such as Berlin or Munich which offers more job opportunities and we won't attempt moving unless at least one of us has a job offer there. I am also aware that there might be regional differences in how working moms are perceived.

Comment: I can't help much, but you did not mentioned if you guys speak German. That would definitely make a difference regarding finding a job. Best of luck!

Comment: The decision whether to move or not is primarily opinion-based and depends on many unknowns such as your qualifications and circumstances as well as luck. I am confused, you state being EU nationals both so a residence permit in Germany would not be any trouble, no? Also I would disagree that working soon after birth is frowned upon, there is even a law that gives you the right to a spot in a Kindertagesstätte from when the baby is 1year old.